# Can I exclude certain repositories from apt-get upgrade?

Tags: apt, repository

I have installed percona extra backup by adding their repository. This worked and I was able to install the software successfully.

However now I am trying to run `apt-get upgrade` and it is trying to update percona. Our client does not wish for this to be included in the regular updates as they wish to control this personally.

Is it possible to exclude a repository when performing this ?

Comment: Can you use synaptic and disable the percona repository? Or mark all upgrade and deselect percona?

Comment: I need to leave the repository active as the client will be upgrading it them selves from the repository. I was hoping there was a switch i can use when running apt-get upgrade to exclude the repository ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can comment those repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list by putting # at first of lines.
also you can disable them in synaptic > setting > repositories > other software.

more information is available at:

[Ubuntu repositories help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

you can hold a package using

`sudo apt-mark hold package_name`

and remove the hold with

`sudo apt-mark unhold package_name`

and also this link will help:

[Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)

Comment: This would work but i would then need to uncomment it afterwards as the client requires the repository to be active for when they choose upgrade it.

Comment: I don't understand!! you should have repo to upgrade and uncomment/uncheck to deactivate it. what do you really want?

Comment: I was hoping to find a switch i could use with apt-get upgrade to exclude the repository from being included so i can apply security patches while not upgrading anything pulled from that repo while leaving it present so the customer can perform the updates themselves.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i was looking for :-)